# Trouble blocking filesystem access with minifilter driver

Tags: driver, windows-10, minifilter

I've been toying around with minifilter drivers and set out to block I/O in certain circumstances. I've been working in PreOperationCallback to decide whether or not to allow the operation; the code in my PreOperationCallback is (**roughly**) as follows:

```
PreOperationCallback (
    _Inout_ PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data,
    _In_ PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects,
    _Flt_CompletionContext_Outptr_ PVOID *CompletionContext
    ) {

            //Deny things with the key in them
            if (wcswcs((Data->Iopb->TargetFileObject->FileName.Buffer), L"77key77")) {
                //Only block IRP_MJ_CREATE, some other functions must not be cancelled
                    if (Data->Iopb->MajorFunction == IRP_MJ_CREATE) {

                    DbgPrint("[CUSTOM] INTERCEPTING OPERATION");

                    Data->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED;
                    Data->IoStatus.Information = 0;

                    return FLT_PREOP_COMPLETE;
                }
            }
        return FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_WITH_CALLBACK;
       }
```

This *half* works: I get asked for administrator approval when deleting any file with the key in it. However, upon granting approval, the file is deleted.
That's cool, but I'm shooting for an error message like this:

[image]

(Yes, sort of like Antivirus usually does)

Can anyone tell me why the administrator is allowed to bypass the filter?

EDIT (Post-question thoughts):
If it was a normal process, not a driver, I would think that the admin has rights to override `ACCESS_DENIED` because the admin had more privileges than the program trying to restrict access, but for a driver I don't feel like this makes any sense.

Comment: a.) drivers are no processes anyway, b.) an admin has a number of privileges _assigned_ but not necessarily also _enabled_, c.) assuming no filter driver is involved, the ACL would still have to be modified prior to removing a file containing an ACE that denies deletion.

Comment: also you mention a `PreOperationCallback` but you should provide detail _which_ of the operations you are using that callback for and moreover which callback you are seeing when it fails. also I think you'll have to have a post-op callback on `IRP_MJ_SET_INFORMATION` which can check for `FileDispositionInformation == FileInformationClass` and whether the field `((PFILE_DISPOSITION_INFORMATION)CallbackData->Iopb->Parameters.SetFileInformation.InfoBuffer)->DeleteFile` is true, _then_ allow or deny it. but given your question only contains little info, it's hard to tell.

Comment: @0xC0000022L I appreciate the input greatly, but as it's been a long time since I asked the question, it'll take me a minute to figure out just what the heck I was talking about. I think I actually figured out that on top of this, I needed to intercept not only IRP_MJ_CREATE, but some others as well. I should figure out what my problem was and come back here to answer it once I do. I believe I also put in a post-op callback, so your information seems to be accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my guess as to what is happening: In Windows Vista and later, the Administrator runs normally with a lower-privilege token. When an access-denied is received, an application can decide to respond by creating an elevated process that runs with a full-privileged token, which can then perform the access.

This scenario shouldn't affect whether your minifilter blocks access, it's just a behavior of how the application (e.g., Windows Explorer) handles the return code. You will probably be seeing a second access to the same file that your minifilter should also be blocking.

If you're not seeing this, perhaps your filter isn't really what is causing the initial access denied error? Have you verified that your code is running via the debugger?

Comment: Actually, moments ago, I switched to automatic volume attachment and that seems to do the trick. I'm still clueless as to why this occurs though. I'd like to find out so we can get an official answer for this question. :/

Comment: @Phixle sounds like your filter wasn't attached to the volume in the first case, and your code was probably never running?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning, I did verify that my code was running. When I stopped the filter, I stopped needing administrator privileges to delete the file. I also verified through the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for something else and bumped into this old question.
It is really old topic but if its still available an answer to it can be made for people reading this, I thought.

The answer to this question is what *lordjeb* pointed out in a comment.

When you install a minifilter driver you need to load it and attach it to desired volumes or just set your filter to load and attach automatically in the inf file. otherwise it won't operate and won't catch the callbacks for that volume IRPs.